# Contrib.Taxonomies - Are they cumulative?

Tags: orchardcms

What I mean;

Is the content associated with a leaf also associated with the branch nodes that leaf terminates?

e.g.

[image]

Associate an item with "c" and it appears in "a","b" and "c".
I'd like the item to only be associated with "c" not "a" and "b" as well.

Have I missed something or is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you don't want c to imply a and b, then c should be a sibling of a and b, not a child.

Comment: So is that the way that taxonomies work then? Its not unreasonable to think that a taxonomy hierarchy in which terms would be exclusively specific exist is it?

Comment: What does it mean in terms of taxonomy? If apes are mammals and mammals are animals, how can an ape not be a mammal and an animal?

Comment: Ok, it makes good sense. In fact I can make a better solution knowing this. Thanks Bertrand.